# Single line text for Headlines with auto hyphens

Tags: experience-editor

We have a lot Headlines and a lot of long words. And on mobile devices we got some problems that the words are too long and it would be nice if we could use

```
&shy;
```

to break the words around

```
body {
   hyphens: manual;
}
```

But I don't think its a good idea to set every headline field from Single/Mulitline line text to rich text. I think then I've some new problems.

When I try to insert the shy directly into the single line text it gets deleted after saving it.

Someone got some good idea how to solve it without ripping the performance?

Sitecore Version 9.0 Upate-2

The problem that the shy is removed seems to be only if I use the custom Experience Editor Extension - modal to edit all fields from a component

when I edit the field in the Content editor or directly in the Experience Editor the shy shows up but is not converted

[image]

Comment: On which version of Sitecore you experiencing this issue? On 9.1.0 (rev. 001564) the saving works fine.

Comment: Do you experience this issue in Experience Editor or Content Editor?

Comment: @TamásTárnok updated Version above 9.0 update 2

Comment: @TamásTárnok you are right it seems to be a problem with the editor Window I am using. That the shy is gone after safe. But When I use the content editor its saved, but then its shown as plain text

Comment: You need render with `@Html.Raw(...)` to not have it HTML encoded. The modal window is a custom implementation? If yes, try to debug it.

Comment: @TamásTárnok I am using the example from habitat to edit all field which uses the "Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "StartFieldEditor", args);" which makes the problems with ripping the shy